# what triggers "new" when document is published in a document library

Tags: sharepoint, document

Whenever I upload a document in the document library, it says new.  What is the timeframe of the "newness" of that document.  Also, can that timeframe be controlled?

Answer (score 4):

Check out this link:

http://www.sharepointcomic.com/archive/2008/12/20/new-item-icon-in-sharepoint-change-how-long-it-shows.aspx

Basically I used to have to change this settings for my clients by using stsadm.exe. If you run:

```
stsadm -o getproperty -pn days-to-show-new-icon
```

That should tell you your current settings for the day duration. So to change the day duration, try:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn days-to-show-new-icon -pv <number of days>
```